# Taking over an Xcode iOS project: code sign error

Tags: xcode, ios, code-signing

I've been asked to take over an iOS development project, and was sent the project files.
I manage to run the project on the simulator, but when I try to run it on my own iPhone, I get an error saying:

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: *former developer name* (*XXXXXXXXXX*)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

How do I take over the project and run it on my own hardware?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your own developer certificate to xCode.  If you've done that and it still doesn't work, I've had success manually removing all references to previous provisioning profiles and developer certificates by opening the xcode project file in a text editor.  Normally you don't have to do that, but sometimes it's the only way I've been able to clear out a problem.  See: [provisioning profile hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742599/provisioning-profile-hell)

Comment: I removed all reference to the previous profiles in the project file, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-ident   and that did the work. Thanks.