# Ad-hoc IPA not getting installed in ipod touch, stuck with installing message

Tags: ios7, provisioning-profile, ipod-touch, ipa

I have been stuck with this weird problem for a while now. The `Ad-hoc IPA` is stuck with '`installing`' message forever in ipod touch 5th gen.

Here is the console output at the time of installation  :

```
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Notice>: 0x387000 handle_install_for_ls:         Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Test.ipa" reTested by atc
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Warning>: [VoiceMemosSyncClient][Orphan-Recovery] (post-sync, no new synced assets) checking for orphaned recordings.
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Notice>: 0x387000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app co.Testapp.Test
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Error>: 0x387000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Warning>: [VoiceMemosSyncClient][Orphan-Recovery] (post-sync, no new synced assets) done.
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Warning>: [ML3MusicLibrary] compacting artwork
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Warning>: [ML3MusicLibrary] removing 0 artwork cache ids no longer used
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod mobile_assertion_agent[121] <Notice>: service_one_connection: Connection closed for client iTunes.
Jul 17 18:13:38 Sreejiths-iPod medialibraryd[220] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} [MLWriter] ending transaction <__NSConcreteUUID 0x16d692f0> 209F4AA6-959D-4FA9-BDA2-E39C052E40EB. shouldCommit=0.
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Error>: 0x387000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.aAeAYo/foo_extracted/Payload/Test.app/Test: 0xe8008015
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Error>: 0x387000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.aAeAYo/foo_extracted/Payload/Test.app
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Error>: 0x1c0a000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Error>: 0x387000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod lsd[130] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app co.Testapp.Test
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: co.Testapp.Test.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod atc[894] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} Database validation succeeded
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod installd[61] <Error>: 0x387000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
Jul 17 18:13:39 Sreejiths-iPod medialibraryd[220] <Warning>: {MediaLibrary} [MLWriter] ending transaction <__NSConcreteUUID 0x16e833d0> 57B6C644-ED9D-4394-B2FF-B98B77107134. shouldCommit=0.
```

Is it related to `Provisioning Profiles`? I followed [Somewhat-same-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742599/provisioning-profile-hell) this post and checked the file as suggested but its still the same.

Has anyone else been facing this issue?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with the Device Profile.

I forgot to add my iPod Touch in the Device list.

Member Center > Certificates > Devices > Add new device . Voila. Everything started working.